# Unable to run npm install & npm run dev for laravel

Tags: npm-install

why the npm install and npm run dev is not run for laravel?

Bellow the error is shown after final the npm run dev will run it show the time estimation seconds to run this,but untill it not complete the run in cmd prompt......

Run step by step:-
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install
npm run dev

Command Prompt:-

npm run dev

> dev
> vite

VITE v4.4.9  ready in 590 ms

➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose
➜  press h to show help

LARAVEL v9.52.15  plugin v0.7.8

➜  APP_URL: http://localhost